# Sending the contents of a hash table over sockets

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, hashtable

Using a TCP server/client setup with sockets, how would I go about sending something like a hash table's contents from the server to the client?

The format I'm looking for is like `IP address: content`.

Comment: You *generally* want to handle things like this by reading the *data* out of the source, sending it to the destination, and let the destination insert it into a hash table on its end. It's *possible* to make other schemes work, but fraught with problems.

Comment: Is it possible to break up the key and value pairs in the hash table, add them to a character string, and then iterate over it so that I can send it to the client?

Comment: That depends on what sort of data they represent to start with. Putting them into a single string without ambiguity may be non-trivial.

Comment: There's no good way to just send the hash table over the socket.  You need to serialize it somehow (I recommend JSON) and then send/recv it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the table on the other end to be rebuilt in the same order?  If so, you need to send the array positions.  If not, you can just send all strings in any order you like and the client can insert.

The easiest way is to send in text mode, although that often makes for a little more work at the client end.  Personally, I'd send the table size as well as the number of strings to expect, and send one entry per line:

```
117 5
puppy
kitten
cub
joey
duckling
```

And if I needed the array positions too, there's nothing wrong with sending them in text as well (but you may prefer binary):

```
117 5
8 puppy
42 kitten
57 cub
101 joey
105 duckling
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to pack your hash table with [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/) binary serialization format, send it through your socket and unpack it on the other side.

e.g. in Ruby (this is just an example - msgpack is available on [many other languages](http://msgpack.org/#crosslang)!) this would give:

```
require "msgpack"
> msg = {"192.0.2.1"=>"foo", "192.0.2.2"=>"bar"}.to_msgpack
 => "\x82\xA9192.0.2.1\xA3foo\xA9192.0.2.2\xA3bar"
> msg.bytesize
 => 29
```